Python Selenium nested div and iframe in html page
I want to access a button in a nested html page: multiple div and iframe
A button is located in a complex html page. How to switch the driver to the corresponding frame.
driver.find_element(By....
driver.switch_to.frame(...
I found that I must switch to iframe by iframe and also <div> must be taken into account
...

            <div id="ModuleBarContainer" class="ModuleBarContainer">
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div id="moduleBarSection_HOME" class="group">
                            <h3 class="hnLnk moduleBarTitle" onclick="setTimeout( function(){  }, 10 );">Startpagina
                            </h3>
                        <div><table class="x269" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td valign="middle">
                                                    <a href="http://link/01.server01#" onclick="javascript:mm( &#39;11337901&#39; )" title="WOD" class="moduleBarNodeLabel" tabindex="-1"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td valign="middle">
                                                                            <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-inject-url="http://link/01/stdimages/module/module_work_order.svg" class="moduleBarModuleImage">
<path d="some-path01 z "></path>

WOD




PO

I was able to locate a nested element moduleBarSection_HOME:
driver_main_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ModuleBarContainer > #accordion > #moduleBarSection_HOME")

How can I do the same thing as
onclick="javascript:mm( '11337901' )
I searched in a lot of documentation without a clear answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79085768/how-to-access-the-attributes-in-an-iframe-in-python
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223018/selenium-get-all-iframes-in-a-page-even-nested-ones
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127442/python-selenium-not-able-to-find-the-fourth-nested-iframes
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

was able to solve my case, thanks internet:
click on button with javascript executor

was able to solve my case, thanks internet:
Locate Xpath: Customizs and control Google Chrome/More Tools/Developper Tools/
Find corresponding button, right click/Copy/Copy Xpath
see also how-to-find-Xpaht-in-Chrome
click on button with javascript executor

code:
'''
po = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/nav[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/div[3]/ul[2]/li[3]/a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", po)
'''

was able to solve my case, thanks internet:

Open developper tools in Chrome: Customise and control Google Chrome/More Tools/Developper Tools/

Find corresponding button, right click/Copy/Copy Xpath
see also how-to-find-xpath-in-chrome

driver.execute_script: see button-with-javascript-executor
po = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div2/div1/div/nav1/ul/li2/ul/div[3]/ul2/li[3]/a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", po)


